# How to perform a query by using URL with question mark in Django?

Tags: django

It seems like the original URL querying function has been removed from Django 3.1. Does anyone know how to do it with a new package?

The url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^portfolio/(?P<title>[\w-]+)/$' , BlogApp_View.displayPortfolio, name='displayPortfolio'),
    path('portfolio/', BlogApp_View.selectPortfolio, name='selectPortfolio'),]
```

The view.py

```
def displayPortfolio(request):
    title = request.GET.get('title')
    portfolio = Article.objects.filter(articleType__name__contains = "Portfolio", title=title)
    print(title)

    DICT = {}

    return render(request, 'Article/', DICT)
```

The problem is now if I visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/Blog/portfolio/?title=A_UAV_Positioning_Approach_Using_LoRa/, it will skip the re_path shows in url.py.
Instead, it goes to the path one.

I have tried str:title method but that is actually not what I want. I prefer using the question mark pattern to finish the query.

Comment: The questionmakr is *not* part of the path. So it will indeed not trigger the view, since it is not part of the path, and thus `re_path` will not do this.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem do you mean I need to rewrite the pattern or it is not possible to use question mark to do query?

Comment: the part after the questionmark is the *querystring*, it is *not* part of the path, hence your `urlpatterns` can not detect this. You will need to write the logic in the view that inspects the `request.GET` (which is a dictionary-like representation of the querystring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part after the questionmark is the [*querystring* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and is *not* part of the path. This thus means that regardless what patterns you write, you can not distinguish on this, since the path patterns, regardless whether it is a `path` or `re_path`, are never matched against a URL with a query string.

You thus should write a single view, and inspect the `request.GET` query dict (which is a dictionary-like representation of the query string and see if it contains a value for `title`.

Your `urlpatterns` thus look like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('portfolio/', BlogApp_View.selectPortfolio, name='selectPortfolio'),
]
```

and in the view, you can see if it contains a title:

```
def selectPortfolio(request):
    if 'title' in request.GET:
        # contains a ?title=…
        title = request.GET.get('title')
        portfolio = Article.objects.filter(
            articleType__name__contains='Portfolio',
            title=title
        )
        data = {'portfolio': portfolio}
        return render(request, 'some_template.html', data)
    else:
        # contains no ?title=…
        # …
        return …
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, it is very clear and it works.